# Move Images in the same axis Xcode-IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to move an image on the same axis,according to data obtained by the device I want the image to move up or down while keeping the center on the Y axis. Thanks.

Comment: so you mean, you want the finger taps on the screen to modify only the position along the y axis, not the x?

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked:

```
imattitude.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(imattitude.transform, 0, accel[2]*75);
```

Where `0` is the value in x axis to move and `accel[2]*75` is the value in axis y for move.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial to help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93563/Introduction-to-iOS-Graphics-APIs-Part-1

The big change is:
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,fromPoint.x , fromPoint.y);

Do not change both, only change one, and used a fixed Y.
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,fromPoint.x , 160);